# How to run Queries on Redshift Database using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to run queries by passing them as string to some supported command of AWS through its CLI.

I can see that the commands specific to AWS Redshift mentioned doesnt have anything which says that it can execute commands remotely

Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/index.html

Need help on this.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use psql. There is no API interface to redshift.

Redshift is based loosely on postgresql however so you can connect to the cluster using the psql command line tool.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html

Comment: I am already using psql @pandelis but i am facing issues regarding "client_encoding" .  I thought of asking it on a different thread and learn if there is anything which can be done from CLI or Powershell Cmdlets

Comment: Since this answer was written, Amazon Redshift has added the **Redshift Data API**. See the other answer for an example.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Redshift Data API to execute queries on Redshift using AWS CLI.

```
aws redshift-data execute-statement 
    --region us-west-2 
    --secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:myuser-secret-hKgPWn 
    --cluster-identifier mycluster-test 
    --sql "select * from stl_query limit 1" 
    --database dev
```

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/announcing-data-api-for-amazon-redshift/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift-data/index.html#cli-aws-redshift-data